# Null pointer exception trying to invoke onClick method from custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, adapter

I was trying to write own adapter class in Android Studio which looks something like this:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<Article> articles;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;


    public Adapter(List<Article> articles, Context context) {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener {

        TextView title, desc, author, published_ad, source, time;
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {

            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.decs);
            author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            published_ad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publishedAt);
            source = itemView.findViewById(R.id.source);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load_photo);

            this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

And the class in which I use my Adapter looks like this:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        adapter = new Adapter(articles, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        LoadJson();

        return view;
    }
```

I am getting an error about null pointer exception: "Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.app2.Adapter$OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference"

Comment: You forgot to set the `OnItemClickListener` on the `Adapter`. You would set it where you're doing the rest of the `RecyclerView` and `Adapter` setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field `Adapter.onItemClickListener` is null until you set it up (what you never do in your actual code)

So you should test if there is a listener before trying to notify it.

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (onItemClickListener != null)
        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
}
```

And I guess you would use it in your `onCreateView` method :)

```java
adapter = new Adapter(articles, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(() -> { System.out.println("Click !") });
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```